# Returning HTTP 403 in a WebAPI method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I return an `HTTP 403` from a `WebAPI` method?  I've tried throwing an `HttpResponseException` with `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden`, and I've tried

```
return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, pEx);
```

Neither of which work.  Both ALWAYS return an `HTTP 200`.  What am I missing?  It has to be something simple but I don't see it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10658604/163495

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081826/net-web-api-throw-exception-return-response-return-error-response-for-404-400-r

Comment: could you share more code...we are unable to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a problem with your routing configuration. Below is a working sample. Put it in your controller and see if it works. If it doesn't, check your routing with a diagnostic tool (i.e. Cobisi Routing Assistant).

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSomeString(int id)
{
    // This method is not allowed!
    return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "This method is not allowed!");
}
```

Comment: Teoman, that does work.  Oddly, it seems to be some sort of interaction with DotNetOpenAuth.  My web api is an endpoint secured with DotNetOpenAuth.  If I call my method without going through the DotNetOpenAuth verification, I get a 403.  However, If I call it by going through DotNetOpenAuth verification, and the verificatoin fails (which is the situation I want to return a 403 with), the same line of code you suggested runs, however no matter what I get a 200 back.  So I guess I'll have to re-post with a dotnetopenauth tag.

Comment: Getting invalid cast from HttpResponseMessage to String

Comment: how to fix the invalid cast to string?

Comment: you always can throw a HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) instead.