# Creating new IHttpActionResult action result methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way I can use the new `IHttpActionResult` interface to return a `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` response message?

I am currently using `return new HttpResponseMessage( HttpStatusCode.NoContent );` 
and would like to convert this into `return NoContent();`.

`IHttpActionResult` has already got `Ok()`, `Conflict()` and `NotFound()` but I cannot find any for `Forbidden()` and `NoContent()` which I need to use in my project.

How easy is it to add other result types?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found this [example site](http://www.sunilrav.com/post/ASPNET-Web-Api-custom-IHttpActionResult-for-HTTP-Forbidden) that shows how to add a custom `IHttpActionResult` method and I've used this to create the `Forbidden()` and `NoContent()` methods with great success.

```
public abstract class CommonApiController : ApiController
{
    public class ForbiddenResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
        private readonly string _reason;

        public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request,string reason)
        {
            _request = request;
            _reason = reason;
        }

        public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            _request = request;
            _reason = "Forbidden";
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,_reason);
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }

    public class NoContentResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
        private readonly string _reason;

        public NoContentResult(HttpRequestMessage request,string reason)
        {
            _request = request;
            _reason = reason;
        }

        public NoContentResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            _request = request;
            _reason = "No Content";
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent,_reason);
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
public class InvoiceController : CommonApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Invoice invoice)
    {
        if(User.IsInRole("Readonly"))
        {
            return Forbidden();
        }

        // Rest of code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 57):

There's no convenience method for `no-content` result because, by default, when a action returns `void`, the response will have the HTTP status 204.

If you wish to explicitly indicate that on the action, you could also return a `StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)` from your action or a

```
ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)).
```

The Unauthorized() convenience method gives you a 401 status so, for Forbidden (403), you would also have to use `StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)` or

```
ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
```

Comment: Unauthorized=401. Forbidden=403.

Comment: Nice, this is the best response.

Comment: In some cases returning `void` is not an option as you'd want to respond with a BadRequest or some other status code in your validation on only send NoContent on success. Returning `StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)` solved this for me, and it's a much cleaner solution that the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I tried the @Intrepid implementation and I ran into some problems. I see two solutions here:

**Solution 1:**
The part: `return Forbidden();` should not work.

The compiler would not recognize this.

Instead it should be: `return new ForbiddenResult(Request, "my reason");`

**UPDATE 1**

**Solution 2:**

I think this is what @Interpid intended in his implementation, but he was missing a few things.

In order to use `return Forbidden();` the `CommonApiController` should be updated with the functions that return the custom `IHttpActionResult` for `Forbidden` and `NoContent`

The class should look like this:

```
public abstract class CommonApiController: ApiController {

    protected ForbiddenResult Forbidden() {
     return new ForbiddenResult(this.Request);
    }

    protected ForbiddenResult Forbidden(string reason) {
     return new ForbiddenResult(this.Request, reason);
    }

    protected NoContentResult NoContent() {
     return new NoContentResult(this.Request);
    }

    public class ForbiddenResult: IHttpActionResult {
     private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
     private readonly string _reason;

     public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request, string reason) {
      _request = request;
      _reason = reason;
     }

     public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request) {
      _request = request;
      _reason = "Forbidden";
     }

     public Task < HttpResponseMessage > ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, _reason);
      return Task.FromResult(response);
     }
    }

    public class NoContentResult: IHttpActionResult {
     private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
     private readonly string _reason;

     public NoContentResult(HttpRequestMessage request, string reason) {
      _request = request;
      _reason = reason;
     }

     public NoContentResult(HttpRequestMessage request) {
      _request = request;
      _reason = "No Content";
     }

     public Task < HttpResponseMessage > ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, _reason);
      return Task.FromResult(response);
     }
    }
   }
```

**Anyway, if I am wrong and @Interpid's answer is correct. What am I missing here to make his implementation work?**

Comment: Updated the answer. Added another alternative solution. I think the second solution is what @Interpid meant in the first place.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea here. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note: you should NOT return a content body with a 204 No Content. I would remove the "protected NoContentResult NoContent(string reason)" method from the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374724/2463738 for more info.

Comment: @valentin Noted. I updated the question. Thank you for noticing

Answer (score 8):

You can now use the following (.Net Standard):

```
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

or (.Net Core 2.1+)

```
return NoContent();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include a reason phrase with your response without adding a sub-class to ApiController, build a ResponseMessage object and return it from the action by the ResponseMessage() method. Try this:

```
public class InvoiceController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Invoice invoice)
    {
        if(User.IsInRole("Readonly"))
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            response.ReasonPhrase = "User has the Readonly role";
            return ResponseMessage(response);
        }

        // Rest of code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked well for me:

```
public class CodeAndReason : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpStatusCode code;
    private readonly string reason;

    public CodeAndReason(HttpStatusCode code, string reason)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(code)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = reason,
            Content = new StringContent(reason),
        };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }

    public static IHttpActionResult NotFound(string reason)
    {
        return new CodeAndReason(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, reason);
    }

    public static IHttpActionResult Conflict(string reason)
    {
        return new CodeAndReason(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, reason);
    }

    public static IHttpActionResult Unauthorized(string reason)
    {
        return new CodeAndReason(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, reason);
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
return CodeAndReason.NotFound("Record {blah} not found");
```