# How to create a filter that returns a forbidden result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a web api filter that checks if the request header has the correct Api key.

If it doesn't, I want to return 403 response code and halt execution (forbidden action)

```
public class ApiPermission : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

        }
}
```

Using the filterContext I know I can do something like:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectTo...
```

**But how can I change the status code to 403 and just return a string and halt execution and stop processing other filters and the controller action?**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also feel like throwing an exception is wrong.

Comment: @JasonBray See my answer

Answer (score 11):

Looks like posted answers not Asp.Net Core 2.1 compatible. In core you can do something like that

```
filterContext.Result = new  ObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState)
{
    Value = null,
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden
};
```

Or maybe it'll be convenient to create class like BadRequest, but for 403 Code.

```
public class ForbiddenObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    public ForbiddenObjectResult(object value)
            : base(value)
    {
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
    }
}

...

filterContext.Result = new ForbiddenObjectResult(filterContext.ModelState);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to throw an exception, you can instead return an `HttpStatusCodeResult`

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result != null) return;   //Another filter has already returned a result so pass it on

    //Do your filtering

    filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden");
}
```

Comment: I cannot find HttpStatusCodeResult. I use StatusCodeResult instead.

Comment: This answer is for ASP.NET MVC, i.e. (System.Web.Mvc). Yes, it looks like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult` is a way to do it for ASP.NET Core. `ControllerBase` offers a [`StatusCode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-3.0) method as a shortcut to creating one of these. I also see a [`ForbidResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.forbidresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) class which interestingly, does not inherit from `StatusCodeResult` I'm curious what the reason for that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw a [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which lets you pass any HTTP code and will halt execution (because its an exception)

```
throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
```

Or look at [Returning HTTP 403 in a WebAPI method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201255/returning-http-403-in-a-webapi-method) which creates an ErrorResponse.

You may also want to consider moving this into an AuthorizationFilterAttribute, because you are checking the user's API Key to authorize them to perform the action.

Comment: Doesn't seem like throwing an exception is right in this case.

Comment: Handling control-flow using exceptions is an antipatter so it should not be advised!

Answer (score 2):

In .NET core (I'm using 3.0), you can make sure code does not subsequently reach the controller action by using the following in the action filter:

```
 filterContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can return:

```
filterContext.Result = new ForbidResult();
```

Comment: This is best as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This tries to do a redirect and returns a bad request (400) if certain authentication schemes aren't set up.

Answer (score 0):

you can throw HttpException :

```
 throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
```

For more details, please visit ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Handling control-flow using exceptions is an antipatter so it should not be advised!